# Changing the color of an entire tile layer in Cocos2D for iOS

Tags: properties, colors, cocos2d-iphone, layer, tiles

In Coco2D, I can loop through every tile, and apply a color to each tile individually. Problem is, that it is slow loading the map.

```
if([blocksCollidable tileAt:tileCoord]!=nil){
    [blocksCollidable tileAt:tileCoord].color = ccc3(255, 100, 255);

}
```

It's not the loop in particular that is making it slow, but applying the color to each tile individually.  Is there a way to apply a color property to an entire tile layer? For instance, I wish there was something like: blocksCollidable.color = ccc3(255, 100, 255);

Comment: That's not possible. Not sure if HKTMXTiledMap can do that, it might. It would certainly be very easy to add to KoboldTouch (http://www.koboldtouch.com), just let me know. The problem why this is so slow with CCTMXTiledMap is that it converts every tile from a quad (4 vertices + texture) to a full-blown CCSprite. This will also increase memory consumption of the tilemap.

Comment: I'll look into HKMXTiledMap, but I remember that not being able to do GIDAt or something else I needed. I can't use another game engine because I've been developing on this for over 2 years. Thanks for the info.